# How many Python scripts can I run using tmux in AWS Lightsail with a single core?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, tmux, amazon-lightsail

I have a number of very simple Python scripts that are constantly hitting API endpoints 24/7. The amount of data being pulled is very minimal and they all query the APIs every few seconds. My question is, is it okay to run multiple simple scripts in AWS Lightsail using `tmux` on a single core Lightsail instance or is it better practice to create a new instance for each Python script?

Comment: Why not run, and check how much ram and cpu you are using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't find any limits mentioned in LightSail for your use case. As long as the end-points are owned by you or you don't get blocked for hitting them continuously, all seems good.

https://aws.amazon.com/lightsail/faq/

You can also set some alarms on Lightsail instance usage to know if you've hit any limits.